# Trouble getting this preloader working (NO LOAD BAR)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So I'm attempting to have a basic preloader for my flash file with a movieclip that has text that changes depending on what % of the file has loaded. And by text, I mean it's telling a short story of sorts as the main part of the file loads. Not just a numerical representation of the % loaded.

I've searched and searched and searched, but everything I've found only uses the progress bar which I don't want!

My flash file is three frames, the first has:

```
var amountLoaded:Number = Math.round(this.getBytesLoaded()/this.getBytesTotal() * 100);

preloadText.gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(amountLoaded));
```

The second frame is:

```
if(_root.getBytesLoaded() == _root.getBytesTotal()) {
gotoAndPlay(3);
}
else {
gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

And the third is the actual meat and potatoes of the file, which works.

The problem is, I get these compiler errors

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 2, Line 1 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getBytesLoaded.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 2, Line 1 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method getBytesTotal.
```

This is driving me batty!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a document class for the stage?  MovieClip(root) is what you would use to call the document class from either a stage frame or a child of the document class.  So, MovieClip(root).getBytesLoaded();

Comment: Oh, I'm not loading any external files- The first two I copied from another site. They used a loading bar though, and I removed that, replacing it with the movieclip with text in it. I made the clip 100 frames long, so the % of file loaded would advance the frames in the clip. I am not an Actionscript wiz, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with coding in various frames on the timeline instead of keeping all code in one external .AS file that works as a single control point for all things in all frames. Now some of your code is at risk of losing scope. Example is.. Variable A in frame 5 means nothing to Variable B which is in frame 6 so they cant work together etc etc.

Anyway this below might help. I haven't used timeline for code in a long while but I'm sure enterFrame will work like this:

**frame 1:**

```
stop(); //stop here until load completes

var amountLoaded:int; //is now Integer not Number; 

//run function to update as the movie loads
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameEnter);

function onFrameEnter(event:Event):void 
{
    amountLoaded = this.getBytesLoaded()/this.getBytesTotal() * 100;

    //show number in textfield called "load_amount"
    load_amount.text = String(amountLoaded) + " %";

    //update messages MC to new frame number 
    //preloadText.gotoAndStop(amountLoaded);

    //checks status of SWITCH element and update according to the found case
    switch (amountLoaded)
    {
       case 0:
       preloadText.gotoAndStop(1); //frame 1

       case 25:
       preloadText.gotoAndStop(2); //frame 2

       case 50:
       preloadText.gotoAndStop(3); //frame 3

       case 75:
       preloadText.gotoAndStop(4); //frame 4

    }

    //if Loaded is equal-to/greater than Total assume ready for frame 3
    if (bytesloaded >= bytestotal) 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameEnter);
        this.gotoAndPlay(3);
            //removeChild(preloadText); //consider this since wont be needed on Frame 3

    }

}
```

Make sure that when you create the textfield...
- It is called "amount_loaded" as the instance name 
- Your font is embedded. **Window**-->**Properties**-->(scroll down to **Character**) and choose font + click **Embed** next to it. When embed options come up make sure you tick Numerals and Punctuation. Good luck

Comment: I think this is probably closer to what I want- but I think the example you provided just has the % loaded returned as a text string of sorts? The movieclip I'm using is several messages that change depending on the amount loaded (0%, 25% at frame 25, 50% at frame 50 etc) that tell a short story. I have a feeling it's right on the tip of my tongue, so to speak.

Comment: I get what you mean. How many different message frames is there in total? Could try if/else statements to change frames in the MessageMC according to the "amountLoaded". This would be inside the enterFrame function too

Comment: There are four- so could make the movieclip just four frames instead of 100 and set it so frame 1 = 0% loaded, 2 =25% and so on?

Comment: Oh I edited too soon. Four is manageable with If/Else checks. I assumed the worst (could be really 100 frames of animation) so the code expects one frame per percent. Yes you could make it just 4 frames long and what you said will still work. Let me show you how in a new edit in a few mins.